# can pseudo elements be used to target descendants?

Tags: css

I am trying to add a calculated width to descendants of an element with a scroll bar in certain situations but cannot seem to get the following to work.  Can pseudo elements be used in this way? If not why not? Would body::-webkit-scrollbar not have the same descendants as body and there for work?

The following is the code I want to work (ie. add a width only if body or parent div has the pseudo element ::-webkit-scrollbar) but I am mostly interested in why it wont work.

```
div::-webkit-scrollbar .child-element, body::-webkit-scrollbar .child-element {
        width: calc(100% - $scrollbarwidth );
}
```

Comment: Post a complete question - MCVE

Comment: No, really; because it should be a children of the pseudo element, and there is not such thing.. (ie: `.scrollbar:before .scrollbarchildren`  this names the childrien of the :before, not the original selector `.scrollbar`). It's much simpler to add a class to this elements.

Comment: @Amit I tried to make my question clearer but im not sure what MCVE is.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet ill work on playing with this though im not 100% sure I understand. Thanks for the starting point!

Comment: If you don't know what [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, you're not paying respect to the people helping you. Read [ask].

Comment: @Amit just never seen the short hand of Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable

Comment: OK, so for future reference, always include relevant markup with such CSS. for example, `._common-modal.is-open` means nothing without markup. That way you could get a solution to your problem regardless of the idea you tried (pseudo elements...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-elements)

> pseudo-elements may only be appended after the last simple selector of
>   the selector.

Not in [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements):

> Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector, and if present it
>   must appear after the sequence of simple selectors that represents the
>   subjects of the selector.

Sometimes, in [Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#pseudo-element-structure):

> Some pseudo-elements are defined to have internal structure. These
>   pseudo-elements may be followed by child/descendant combinators to
>   express those relationships. Selectors containing combinators after
>   the pseudo-element are otherwise invalid.

Comment: thanks @Oriol that is what I was looking for. However if that is the case is there anyway to see if the parent has the ::-webkit-scrollbar class?

Comment: @ReganPerkins You want to select an element only if it has a scrollbar? Maybe `element:has(::-webkit-scrollbar)` would theoretically work, but browsers don't support this kind of things yet.

Comment: im trying to select a descendant if the parent has webkit-scrollbar showing. ( i have a modal that is a child of body. if body suddenly gets a scrollbar in safari/chrome i need to subtract the scrollbar width from the width of the modal. )